# Compojure: optional URL parameter

Tags: clojure, compojure

I want to define a resource in Compojure like this:

```
(ANY "myres/:id" [id] (handler))
```

and I want the :id to be optional (depending on whether or not the ID is specified my API will behave differently).

This works ok if I try to access

```
http://mydomain/myres/12
```

However if I try to access

```
http://mydomain/myres
```

without specifying an ID, I get 404.

Is there any way to have the parameter :id to be optional?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about creating 2 different route one with id and another without it and calling your handler from both route as shown below:

```
(defn handler
    ([] "Response without id")
    ([id] (str "Response with id - " id)))

(defroutes my-routes
    (ANY "myres" [] (handler))
    (ANY "myres/:id" [id] (handler id)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution which I will definitely apply! It's a shame the :id parameter is not considered optional by default. I don't like the idea of having to define two routes especially if I have many resources following the same pattern :(